# Would you use a numeric or semantic label as column values?

Tags: database, database-design, language-agnostic

I have certain columns that should "states", for example "done", "not done", "waiting", "yes","no" etc.
The options I have are:

1. integer column, documenting the mapping, eg: 0=not done, 1=done etc...
2. string column, with the real word "done", "not done" etc.
3. enum data type?
   The question is, there is some rationale to decide which one to use?
   Integers will save space of course. But code will be harder to read, db harder to understand, documentation harder to maintain.
   It's worth the saving?

Is enum data type combining the benefit of 1 and 2?

I have a personal preference for solution 2 or 3, readability, but I don't know if database will look weird after that, or  if the performance will be a key point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, I always go for solution 1 (integer column), but this column is a foreign key to a new table listing the possible states. With this solution:

- DBMS auto-checks valid values.
- Practically self-documentied in table of states.
- Space occupied does not grow a lot with long state names
- Avoids duplicate names for same state (done/Done/DONE!/finished).
- May easily add new states afterwards.
- The new table can be reused if states are needed in other tables (or other columns in the same table).
- States can have more information than just a short name: single letter abbreviation for state, long and short names, description of when to use this state, order for display in listings, etc. All of these can be columns in the table of states.